# postgres performance - query hanging - query analysis tools and configuration question

Tags: postgresql, freeze

We have a query we have been using for several months. It recently started hanging. The query is a join from 4 tables. One of those tables is only a few thousand records, one a hundred thousand, and 2 are about 2 million. It has been running in about 20 seconds for several months. 
After several attempts to identify the issue by adding indexes to unindexed fields with no avail we modified one of the large tables to be a sub query with the result of 100000 records versus 2 million. The query now runs in 20 about seconds.

Explain of the query that hangs produces:

```
 Limit  (cost=1714850.81..1714850.81 rows=1 width=79)
```

While explain of the query that runs in 20 seconds produces:

```
Limit  (cost=1389451.40..1389451.40 rows=1 width=79)
```

The query that hangs is larger, but does not indicate a significant difference.

Questions:

- Are there thresh holds in postgres that cause it to use system
  resources differently, i.e. disk buffering versus memory buffering?
  The query that hangs shows one cpu with 100% usage. The system is
  Linux. Iotop does not show extraordinary io usage. The system has 32
  GB RAM and 8 processors. Postgres does not appear to by loading the
  system heavily.
- Are there other tools that can be applied? The query sub select
  worked in this case but we may not be able to reduce a join
  dimensions in this way in the future.

As a note the full explain does not show a markedly different execution plan. 
Thanks, Dan

Comment: You might want to check the [memory settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-resource.html) in your `/etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresl.conf` and consider the [tips here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server). You could experiment with increasing the values and see if that alleviates the problem. If it does, careful experimentation may be able to tell you which setting was the bottleneck.

Comment: The optimizer may choose a totally different execution plan when the data change or get more. The main tool is `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` (if the query can complete). Query tuning is kind of an art.